# Should I use select count(*) for counting records or having a field like comments_no for tables like post, comments?

Tags: innodb, select, count, update, mysqli

In my recent project which is about social networking for an Asian country, I'm in doubt whether I use the below SQL statement for counting records:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) shareLikeNo FROM user_share_like WHERE jusid=$jusid
```

Or update a field like comment_no in shares(posts) table?
I have fields like shares_no,comments_no,likes_no. Everytime a user click `like button` the likes_no field will be incremented and other fields as I explained.
This way I have to update every record each time a user post a comment or shares a post or likes a post.
Should I use `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblname` and so on for getting the record count or just updating a record.
There will about 10 to 20 posts each second. Site's traffic will rose.
Which approach should I use? Which one is more expensive?

**EDIT:**
I've used `use index(PRIMARY)` as below to speed things up:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) shareLikeNo FROM user_share_like USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE jusid=$jusid
```

Another approach is:

```
SELECT SUM(1) shareLikeNo FROM user_share_like WHERE jusid=$jusid
```

Is this a better approach?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT COUNT(id)`. Use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead. With no hints. MySQL optimizer has some blind spots.

Comment: And I hope you have an index on `jusid`.

Comment: It is indexed indeed.

Comment: Is there a requirement that the count must always be correct?  Or do you have some flexibility to return approximate results?  Does it matter if the count eventually matches reality or can it remain approximate forever?  For example, if all comments on a YouTube video were halted and there were actually 1 million comments while the counter said 995,867 comments, no one would probably care about a discrepancy of 4000-some comments.  Other systems will have other sorts of requirements for accuracy and consistency.

Answer (score 1):

1. How frequent do you need to perform this query?

   If it is very rarely, then, perhaps it doesn't matter. And you could do "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...", do no need to use "SELECT COUNT(id)". SELECT COUNT(id) is not necessary in your case. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181272/what-does-select-count1-from-table-name-on-any-database-tables-mean) for more about when to use SELECT COUNT(1) etc.
2. As pointed out by Justin Cave above, does it need to be accurate all the time?

   If you need it to be accurate, you might have to suffer the cost of the query.

   If not, perhaps you could consider caching the value and only perform the query once every time period (once per 5 seconds?)

Answer (score 0):

There are many subtle things that could be involved, these will help direct the discussion:

SHOW CREATE TABLE shareLikeNo;

SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'shareLikeNo';

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';

If your traffic gets too busy, you may have abandon the notion of real-time updating of "likes".